# Debugging TikZ and PGFPlots compatibility issue

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, installing, incompatibility, debugging

I just tried to compile an old TikZ code (which as far as I recall compiled perfectly in the past and was not changed in the meanwhile) and I faced some serious compilation issues related to TikZ.

The last few lines of log are:

```
Package pgfplots: loading complementary code for your PGF version...

(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/oldpgfcompatib/pgfplot
soldpgfsupp_misc.code.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.236 ...e\let\pgfutil@next\relax\fi \pgfutil@next
                                                  }
```

Little googling around pointed that the problem might be some incompatibility between TikZ elements on my system. Since, as far as I recall, I didn't change my code and it compiled in the past, I believe that the problem indeed relates to my installation of TikZ. I'm using `MacTeX` on a Snow Leopard Mac OS, and I installed the CVS version of TikZ in my home directory. It seems, however, that `pdflatex` uses the older version of TikZ which is to be found in `/usr/local/texlive/2012`.

I don't really know where to start and debug this issue. For the reference the complete log file is [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/9709624/tikz-compatibility-issue.log).

How can I fix the installation of TikZ? Is it correct behavior that TikZ uses code from both the main installation of `texlive` and from my local installation? If this question fails (and it is I guess a border case) to be valid to TeX.SE, then I hope you can at least point me to sources/places where I can get some help with this.

Comment: Looking at your log, you are using the CVS version of TikZ/PGF but the TL version of pgfplots.  There is a test in the `pgfplots` code which looks for a certain command to decide whether or not the PGF version is correct.  It would appear that this is not passing the test.  I don't know why, but that is where to start looking.  The file with the test in it is: pgfplotsoldpgfsupp_loader.code.tex

Comment: @AndrewStacey This makes lots of sense - I do not recall any manual installation of `pgfplots`. However, this is somehow still too cryptic for me.

Comment: Given that you've updated TikZ/PGF, how about also updating PGFPlots?  That might fix the issue without needing an in depth analysis of the files.

Comment: It seems like my PGFPlots was updated (without any manual tweaking), but the TikZ was not the latest. I updated TikZ and it seems to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the problem was some mixture of version of `PGFPlots` and of `TikZ`. I updated `TikZ` manually to the latest version ([here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/builds/), 04.11.2012) - before hand I had the release from August 2012. The `PGFPlots` version that I have installed (via the normal TeX Live Utility updates) is 1.7.

Now, together it works again fine.